# Can I convert an EPS file to CDR in CorelDraw4

Tags: corel-draw

I have a wordle file that was created on a website, saved, and sent to me in an EPS file. My question is, if I am running CorelDraw4 can I convert that EPS file to a CDR file?

Answer (score 1):

Just import the `.eps` file in CorelDraw and then save it as a `.cdr` file. It should be able to open it.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers.

Sometimes you can achieve better results if you convert EPS to PDF at first, then import PDF in CorelDraw.

Answer (score 0):

Corel 4 is an ancient almost prehistoric version. I am not sure if EPS support was available.

If you refer to **X4** (Aka **14**) yes, there are 2 methods.

**1)** Choose every format when using the File > Open comand.

**2)** Open a new document and import the EPS file.

Sometimes one method works better than the other.

When you save your file, you will be asked to save it a s cdr.